# Why is anyone with API access allowed to cancel the 'attachToTangle' operation of another user?

Tags: iri-node, iri-legacy-api, attach-to-tangle

In the IRI, there is no filter that prevents anyone from cancelling another users 'attachToTangle' operation when the POW is in progress.

See API.java, `case "interruptAttachingToTangle"`

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

It's the responsability of the node owner to configure it's node properly. The recommended setting is to not allow remote-POW (therefore interruptAttachingToTangle is a NOOP).

If the node owner allows remote-pow, it is probably a good idea to not allow remote call to interruptAttachingToTangle. (using remote-limit-api parameter)

Comment: Cancelling is still allowed locally (A script running on the node may have the ability to do it). Allowing the light-node-client to cancel it's own request would requires some kind of authentication. Such mechanism isn't implemented (yet ?).