# What IRI API commands should only be executed on a node that is synced to the latest milestone?

Tags: iri-node, iri-legacy-api

I want to load balance commands to my nodes. But not all nodes are equally fast. Some commands do not need a node that is completely up to date to finish successfully, like `attachToTangle`. Therefore I want to make sure that the slower nodes only get commands where it is not so important to be up to date.

What are these commands? Can someone provide a list of them (without the adminstrative commands related to node info and neighbors) and a short explanation why they can/cannot/should not be processed by a delayed node?

For example: what about `storeTransactions` and `broadcastTransactions`?

Bonus question: are there some commands that build on one another? With that I mean that it is important that the same node processes the next command from the same client.

Comment: Quick response to the bonus question : no (it's a rest API... so it is stateless)

Comment: I do not think that it is stateless as every node might have different data. For example if node A provides tips, node B does not necessarily know them (yet?).

Comment: Indeed, but it is not a problem. A node don't need to know branch and trunk to broadcast a transaction.

Comment: @SaintHill for examply by comparing the latestMilestoneIndex of several nodes. Usually the slower nodes are only off by one from my experience.

Comment: @SaintHill I do not provide proofs. The method I use is to query all the milestones of the load balanced nodes and compare them. Another possibility would be to query public nodes. Certainty is only relative as it is related to the view of the nodes you choose. Afaik there is no way to query the milestone from the coo directly.

Comment: I query the data of all load balanced nodes from time to time (currently only two but I tried with 100 as well). I didn't calculate a proper probability and didn't bother with incorrectly reported data (yet). But let's stop here, doesn't belong into the comments imo.

Comment: https://iotanode.host/ does exactly the same. It queries public nodes and interprets the responses. If you know of a better way, please let me know.

Comment: How to find the latest milestone: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/determining-the-latest-milestone-with-statistical-certainty-to-a-confidence-lev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of all API calls (except nodeInfo and neighbors related calls), with a brief description of what it does. Hope it helps.

(don't hesitate to edit, or leave a comment is something is wrong)

**storeMessage**

Only for testnet

**attachToTangle**

Run the pow. Safe to run on an non sync node. It make sense to dispatch those calls to the machine with highest computing power.

**broadcastTransactions**

Broadcast transactions to direct neighbors, can run safely on a desynchronised node

**findTransactions**

Search for transactions. Results will be more accurate on synced node

**getBalances**

Get balances on adresses. Results will be more accurate on sync node (this call is probably used by some wallet implementation as pre-check of the validity of the transaction)

**getInclusionStates**

Check if transactions are referenced by another set of transactions. (typical use case is to check if a particular transaction is validated by a milestone)
It make more sense on a fully sync node.

**getTips**

Return the tips in a specific IRI instance
Make sense on any node, mainly for monitoring IMO

An IRI instance keep an in memory cache of transactions that don't have any approvers yet (i.e. tips). This call returns the content of this cache. In other words, this call is just a way to be informed of the internal state of the IRI and I don't think it can be useful from a purely functional perspective. (i.e. picking tips from here to attach a transaction don't make sense because the consistency check is not done)

**getTransactionsToApprove**

This trigger the random walk, therefore it's very important to execute this on a fully-sync node.

**getTrytes**

Return transactions trytes. Results will be more accurate on sync node.

**interruptAttachingToTangle**

Shouldn't be remotely accessible (see [Why is anyone with API access allowed to cancel the 'attachToTangle' operation of another user?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/why-is-anyone-with-api-access-allowed-to-cancel-the-attachtotangle-operation-o))

**storeTransactions**

It simply store a batch of transactions in the local tangle (don't broadcast).
<strike>I don't see a use case for this one. Can be useful for maintenance maybe ? IMO, this shouldn't be remotely accessible.</strike> This call is used by spammers. Don't requires a fully sync node.

It appears that spammers use it generaly in conjuction with broadcast transactions. In this case if you "storeTransactions" on node A, and just after that "broadcastTransaction" on node B : this won't broadcast anything.

It don't change the fact that those calls are stateless, it's just that the current usage by spammers make the fair assumption that 2 successive calls to store, then broadcast will be executed on the same instance (but nothing in the protocol offer that guarantee).

**getMissingTransactions**

Return the transactions known only by their hash. (details of the transaction aren't yet in the local tangle)
Make sense on any node, mainly for monitoring.

When a node receive a transaction, this transaction contains the hash of the branch and trunk transactions. If one of them(or both) is(are) not in the local tangle, then the hash(es) is(are) added to a queue of "missing transactions".
This call return that queue. The size of the queue is an interesting indicator to evaluate the "sync state" of the node.

**checkConsistency**

Check consistency of a set of transactions. It make more sense to run it on fully sync node.

**wereAddressesSpentFrom**

This call is use to prevent address re-use. Results will be more accurate on sync node (this call is used by some wallet implementations)

**all others**

Invocation of IXI module (probably better to run of fully sync node)

Comment: @SaintHill because I don't see any use case for it.

Comment: From my log files I saw that many spammers use storeTransactions in combination with broadcastTransactions. Does broadcastTransactions store the transactions, too? Does storeTransactions need to know referenced transactions?

Comment: storeTransactions don't need to know the trunk and branch. broadcastTransactions don't store them: it just check the validity (not the consistency) and send to neighbors.

Comment: Thank you, that contains most of the information I needed. You helped me a lot. Just for reference: still not clear to me is (a) what getTips is for. I assume it makes sense to request this from a recent node otherwise the tips are old and maybe not tips anymore, (b) I assume that it makes sense to store transactions at the node the client is using currently so that they are available there, (c) no idea what getMissingTransactions is for.

Comment: @mio I edited my answer with some more details.

Comment: The answer and the comment above with regard to broadcastTransactions are contradictory in my opinion. You say a broadcast without store on the same node isn't going to broadcast anything in the answer. After a casual look at the IRI code I would assume that broadcastTransactions broadcasts them even if they were not stored on the same node before. Therefore I would say that it is not necessary to execute them on the same node for a single client.

Comment: My point is if you "store only" on node A, then node B don't have knowledge of those transactions... and if you ask node B to broadcast unknown transactions nothing can be broadcasted.